# Error returning when counting records in a query grouped in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a problem trying to group some records and trying to count the number of records returned by a query is adding an example:

```
07  COMERCIO                               92         
15  SERVICIOS OTROS                        41  
01  AGRICULTURA, GANADERIA Y SILVICULTURA  141  
04  INDUSTRIA MANUFACTURERA                28  
10  BANCA Y FINANZAS                       5    
12  ADMINISTRACION PUBLICA                 16  
03  MINERIA                                3  
16  HOGAR                                  2  
08  HOTELES Y RESTAURANTES                 37  
11  EMPRESARIAL                            21  
14  SOCIAL Y SALUD                         4  
06  CONSTRUCCIÓN                           3  
09  TRANSPORTE                             30  
13  EDUCACION                              10
```

This is query:

```
SELECT 
    AGRUP.VC_CODDET AS CHR_SECECO,
    AGRUP.VC_NOMDET AS VC_SECECO,
    0 AS INT_NROPRESTAMO,
    COUNT(*)  INTO_BENEFICIARIOS,
    0 AS DEC_SALCON      
    FROM TB_JSI_PRESTAMO_DETALLE PREDET
INNER JOIN TB_JSI_PRESTAMO PRE ON 
PRE.INT_IDPRESTAMO=PREDET.INT_IDPRESTAMO
INNER JOIN TB_JSI_BENEFICIARIO_IFI BENIFI ON 
BENIFI.INT_IDBENEIFI=PRE.INT_IDBENEIFI
INNER JOIN TB_JSI_OPERACION OPE ON PRE.INT_IDOPE = OPE.INT_IDOPE AND 
TRUNC(TO_DATE(OPE.DT_FECVEN))>TRUNC(TO_DATE('30/09/2018', 'DD/MM/YY'))   
INNER JOIN TB_JSI_CIIU CIIU ON PRE.INT_IDACT = CIIU.INT_IDACT AND 
PRE.INT_IDSEC=CIIU.INT_IDCLAS 
INNER JOIN TB_JSI_TABLA_DET SECECO ON SECECO.INT_IDDET=CIIU.INT_IDCLAS 
INNER JOIN TB_JSI_AGRUPA_SECTOR AGRSEC ON SECECO.INT_IDDET = 
AGRSEC.INT_IDSEC 
INNER JOIN TB_JSI_TABLA_DET AGRUP ON AGRSEC.INT_IDAGRU = AGRUP.INT_IDDET 
INNER JOIN TB_JSI_TABLA_DET MON ON OPE.INT_IDMON = MON.INT_IDDET
INNER JOIN TB_JSI_IFI IFI ON OPE.INT_IDIFI = IFI.INT_IDIFI 
WHERE TRUNC(PREDET.DTE_FECPRO) = (
            SELECT 
                    TRUNC(DTE_FECPRO)
            FROM (SELECT 
                    DTE_FECPRO
                  FROM TB_JSI_PRESTAMO_DETALLE
                  WHERE DTE_FECPRO<=TO_DATE('30/09/2018','DD/MM/YY')
                  AND DEC_SALDOL>0
                  ORDER BY DTE_FECPRO DESC)
                  WHERE ROWNUM = 1
            ) 
            AND (NULL IS NULL OR OPE.INT_IDTIPPRO =2) 
            AND (NULL IS NULL OR OPE.INT_IDMON = 364)
            AND (NULL IS NULL OR OPE.INT_IDIFI=72)
            GROUP BY AGRUP.VC_CODDET, AGRUP.VC_NOMDET
```

and should return this result

```
07  COMERCIO                               92  
15  SERVICIOS OTROS                        41  
01  AGRICULTURA, GANADERIA Y SILVICULTURA  141  
04  INDUSTRIA MANUFACTURERA                28  
10  BANCA Y FINANZAS                       4    
12  ADMINISTRACION PUBLICA                 16  
03  MINERIA                                3  
16  HOGAR                                  2  
08  HOTELES Y RESTAURANTES                 37  
11  EMPRESARIAL                            21  
14  SOCIAL Y SALUD                         4  
06  CONSTRUCCIÓN                           3  
09  TRANSPORTE                             30  
13  EDUCACION                              10
```

since I have these records and when counting I should return 4 and not 5

```
269516  10  BANCA Y FINANZAS        1   
269558  10  BANCA Y FINANZAS        1   
269592  10  BANCA Y FINANZAS        2   
269611  10  BANCA Y FINANZAS        1
```

Comment: I think while joining the tables, in some of the tables, there are two entries which is mapped to single entry from other tables. You need to find that table first. Please execute the following query to prove the same. ------ select clause:  
 SELECT 
    AGRUP.VC_CODDET AS CHR_SECECO,
    AGRUP.VC_NOMDET AS VC_SECECO,
    0 AS INT_NROPRESTAMO,
    0 AS DEC_SALCON      
    FROM ------------ remove the group by clause and add two more conditions: AND AGRUP.VC_CODDET = '10' AND AGRUP.VC_NOMDET = 'BANCA Y FINANZAS'

Comment: The posted query has a projection of five columns but your output has only three columns. You should post the version of the code which produced the results you think are wrong.

Comment: Oracle is immensely reliable. It is impossible for COUNT() to produce `5` from only four records. So the most likely explanations are  **(1)** your table actually has five records or **(2)** you have a misconfigured join which is producing a duplicate record somehow or **(3)** your query executes `sum()` not `count()`.

Comment: Beyond that advice, there's not much we can do to help. Your query involves eleven tables. We don't have your data model, we don't have your data, we don't understand the business rules you're implementing. So there's really no way we can debug this code.

Comment: Yes. Please refer [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ac810907be8fef4eb2dd4e5c3c3e5bb9) -- I have written query for you here. This will return 5 values. You need to add Primary/Unique column of each table in this query and need to find in which table it has 2 records available.

Comment: this is the result of query tejash                                                                               
        10 BANCA Y FINANZAS 0 0    
        10 BANCA Y FINANZAS 0 0                
        10 BANCA Y FINANZAS 0 0      
        10 BANCA Y FINANZAS 0 0    
        10 BANCA Y FINANZAS 0 0

Comment: Tejash my code:      https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=30d41b20e210a07b8c1459074ae13d10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Roller, I have analyzed the result and it is now clear that one of the tables used in the query has two records with the matching condition and that is why it is returning 5 and not 4.

You just need to identify the table and if you are not able to, then use the following trick.

First of all, identify the table, basis of which you are saying that there must be 4 rows and then use that table's PK in the count with distinct as follows:

```
 COUNT(DISTINCT MY_PK)
```

Comment: You must try with distinct PK from the table which gives surety of 4 records.

Comment: Thanks Tejash----ORA-00980